# How to find execution time of a java non-blocking method

Tags: java, performance, metrics, execution-time

I want to get execution time of a non-blocking method. Normally it can be done with a `System.CurrentTimeMills()` , Can i use that method in here also. And I like to Know a way to get metrics of non-blocking method.Can it do ?

Comment: yes you can use that in this case as well. get currenttimemillis() int the first line and calculate difference in the line immediately preceding any of the return statement you have

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the same on a non-blocking call as well. But where you put the measuring code can differ. Some approaches are,

- If you are using things like `CompleteableFuture`, you can add a measurement check in the particular `then` logic.
- If you are on callbacks, you can wrap the callback and do the calculation (More info at https://www.ysofters.com/2016/03/18/measuring-execution-time-of-asynchronous-calls/ )

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a "non blocking method". This term is sometimes used for methods that don't use blocking IO and sometimes to methods that initiate some work which will be finished in the future.

You probably mean the latter - and there is no general method to measure their time, because it really depends on what the method is doing. In some specific cases (like when the method returns a `Future`) this might be simple. In some specific cases (the method sends a message to an external system) - it might be impossible.